# Disabled network when execute a bash script at runlevel 0

Tags: bash, ubuntu, networking, runlevel

I'm running a script when i shutdown my pc. I'm running a ubuntu 14.04 and I have my script "save_log.sh" in "/etc/init.d/". This script has execution permission (sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/save_log.sh). I have also created a link in "/etc/rc0.d/" with target "/etc/init.d/save_log".

I have tested that this script is running when shutdown my laptop (a piece but is running).

I'm trying save a logs file and upload to S3 (Amazon Web Services). For this task I'm making a "tar.gz" with all logs files with a specific file name. This file name depends of IP of server (or laptop).

When I run this script in my console is work successfully and the file is created with a file name that contents IP (of my laptop) and this file is uploaded to S3. When I shutdown my laptop the file is created but the name has not IP and the file is not uploaded.

I have created a log for this script and I added output for ifconfig command:

> ifconfig: lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1
>   Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING
>   MTU:65536 Metric:1 RX packets:6432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0
>   frame:0 TX packets:6432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>   collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:1159509 (1.1 MB) TX bytes:1159509
>   (1.1 MB)

This output have not an IP of network. In runlevel0, is network disabled? Is possible activation? Any idea to solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

Content in my /etc/rc0.d/ (ubuntu 14.04):

```
eltortuganegra@eltortuganegra:~$ ll /etc/rc0.d/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 jun 11 16:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 152 root root 12288 jun 12 09:07 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 jun 11 13:29 K01save_logs -> /etc/init.d/save_logs.sh*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    17 jun  9 10:27 K09apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 jun  9 10:14 K10unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 jun  9 10:14 K20kerneloops -> ../init.d/kerneloops*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    19 jun  9 11:35 K20memcached -> ../init.d/memcached*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    15 jun  9 10:14 K20rsync -> ../init.d/rsync*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    27 jun  9 10:14 K20speech-dispatcher -> ../init.d/speech-dispatcher*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    22 jun 11 11:07 K21spamassassin -> ../init.d/spamassassin*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   353 mar 13 02:33 README
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 jun  9 10:14 S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    17 jun  9 10:14 S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    22 jun  9 10:14 S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 jun  9 10:14 S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 jun  9 10:14 S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 jun  9 10:14 S90halt -> ../init.d/halt*
```

I revised in a Debian distribution the rc0.d directory and I found:

> K06networking -> ../init.d/networking

I suppose that is the link that is executed for stop network but in my Ubuntu this link does not exist. I suppose that if I rename my link with a number under K07 then network would be enable and my script "save_logs.sh" would run normally.

How can I know when network is disabled or how can I execute my script before network is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes network will be disabled.  You will want to run your script prior to the network being disabled. It will usually disable itself in the same runlevel you are booting to.

As an example on a SUSE linux system, check this out:

```
test01:/etc/rc.d # ls -latd *rc*/*network*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  3  2009 rc2.d/K17network -> ../network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  3  2009 rc2.d/S05network -> ../network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  3  2009 rc3.d/K17network -> ../network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  3  2009 rc3.d/S05network -> ../network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  3  2009 rc5.d/K17network -> ../network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  3  2009 rc5.d/S05network -> ../network
test01:/etc/rc.d #
```

(your directories may vary depending on which linux you are using)

You'll notice the start and stop of the network script is in the same run level.  In my case, if I boot up to runlevel 3, the start and stop takes place in run level 3.  Start is S05 and stop is K17.

Things are run in numerical order, so if I were to run your logging script on my runlevel 3 machine I would want to put it at K16.

Or to be safe I'd create the logging script for all three run levels

```
rc2.d/K16logging
rc3.d/K16logging
rc5.d/K16logging
```

Does this help?

Comment: hi ben! I have ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop. I have created simbolic link in /etc/rc0.r/K01save_logs.sh and target of this link is "/etc/init.d/save_logs.sh"

Comment: and target of this link is "/etc/init.d/save_logs.sh". I have edited question for add this information. Then, I think that name of symbolic link and target link is correct. If i want run this script only when machine is shutdown then I should use only /etc/rc0d/, is correct? thanks you!

Comment: Sure you can do that, just realize as you suspected the networking will be shut off before then since all the /etc/rc[runlevel].d/K* scripts will be run first.  So you'll need another hack to put an ip address on the interface and then take it off.

Comment: Hi ben!I have created another links in rc2.d, rc3.d, rc4.d and rc5.d folders and now i can get IP from ifconfig statement. I'm confused. If i'm logged in my ubuntu desktop (i suppose that is runlevel 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 not?) and I open a console and execute a shutdown instruction, is system changing to runlevel 0?

Comment: I doing test and I verified that if I do a shutdown from console the script "save_log.sh" is execute 2 times. In rc0.d and rcX.d with X being a number for my desktop.

Comment: Hi, the run level is set in the /etc/inittab file and there are comments in there as well of what a run level is.  2, 3, and 5 are the valid run levels when your computer is on and when they are then powered off.  Unless you do any fancy run level changes while the server is up (and I am guessing not, most people do not), then you should put your log script in run level 2, 3, and 5, not run level 0

Comment: Additionally, you generally don't need any scripts in the other run levels, just 2, 3, and 5 for pretty much any type of applications you want to start and stop. So your log script you should put it in run level 2, 3, and 5. Start it with a "K" and have it run before your network script runs.

Comment: Hi @ben, I checked that if I have a link un all rcX.d directories and I shutdown the laptop then the script is executed twice. One in rc5.d (at desktop runlevel). I suppose that is when I logout from session. Other one in rc0.d (shutdown).

I understand that the link must have a Kxx prefix where xx is a number under Kyy-network where yy is a number. I checked a another debian and I have not a link like:

`K06networking -> ../init.d/networking`

How I have not this link in my rc5.d folder I suppose that **K01save_log.sh** is a correct name.

Comment: Unless you change run levels while you the system is on, you only need them in the 2, 3, and 5 run levels and not the 0 run level.